# How do I make a debian binary out of my stacks and get it listed as a ros package?

Tags: ros, binary, ubuntu, rospackage, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a stack that's fairly well-behaved with the standard ros tools and such (rosmake cleanly, etc) and listed on ROS.org so it's known by the ROS indexer.  How do I get it from this stage to where someone else can do an 'apt-get install PACKAGE-NAME' at the command-line?

Package in question: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rcommander_core
Repository: https://code.google.com/p/gt-ros-pkg.rcommander-core/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34574/how-do-i-make-a-debian-binary-out-of-my-stacks-and-get-it-listed-as-a-ros-package?/) by [haidai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1020/haidai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems that you already have it listed on ros.org as you posted the link.

For a release see here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/release given that this is still valid.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haidai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1020/haidai/) on 2012-05-22**:
Does listing it on ros.org impact how it'll be released?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-22**:
Listing it on ros.org is independent but should usually come first.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-23**:
I created a guide to listing packages on ros.org at: http://ros.org/wiki/Repositories/IndexSubmission